# PowerPoint VBA - Preserving Custom CommandBar Settings on Close

Tags: vba, add-in, powerpoint

I have developed a PowerPoint add-in for versions 2003 and earlier that generates a custom commandbar/toolbar on install.

I have no difficulty removing this commandbar on uninstall, but because it uses the `Auto_Close` event to do so, it also deletes the toolbar every time PowerPoint closes, preventing the user from permanently customizing the commandbar's position.

I've tried a conditional delete by checking if the add-in is registered or loaded, but `Auto_Close` seems to run before any unloading or deregistration.

Any ideas on how to delete the commandbar ONLY when the add-in is being uninstalled?

```
Sub Auto_Close()
Dim pptAddin As AddIn

    For Each pptAddin In AddIns
        If pptAddin.Name = "AddInName" And _
            pptAddin.Registered <> msoTrue Then
            Application.CommandBars("CommandBarName").Delete
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good idea to do what you're doing - deleting your CommandBar when PowerPoint closes. That way if there is ever an error, your add-in doesn't leave artifacts in the UI that don't work.

For managing state though, many folks use `GetSetting` and `SaveSetting` for reading/writing to a sandboxed area in the Registry for VB/VBA programs. Look up the following functions on this [page](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helpcategory14.aspx?CategoryID=CH080154379&lcid=1033&NS=POWERPNT%2EDEV&Version=14&tl=2&CTT=4): `GetSetting`, `SaveSetting`, `GetAllSettings`, `DeleteSetting`. You can use these to manage your add-in's CommandBar between PowerPoint instances. It's relatively simple to use - [here's a tutorial](http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip60.htm) for Excel that would apply equally to PowerPoint.

Comment: Thank you for reading through to my actual requirement and, of course, for the help. Much, much appreciated.